# Начало работы с JOGL

Tags: jogl, java, opengl

Я скачал [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/). Создал проект в Идее. И попытался запустить "Hello World" программу. В результате получил такое исключение:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:117)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.access$000(NativeLibLoader.java:51)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader$1.run(NativeLibLoader.java:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.loadGlueGenRT(NativeLibLoader.java:68)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JVMUtil.<clinit>(JVMUtil.java:56)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:1145)
    at EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)`

Это самая первая строчка в коде:

```
    // setup OpenGL Version 2
    GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
```

Когда я вывел в консоль значение `java.library.path`, то там действительно не оказалось папки с JOGL. Я предположил, что нужно добавить это значение в переменную окружения. Но всё равно не работает. Может, я указал не ту папку или не ту переменную...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

java.library.path - это не переменная оуркжения, а свойство рантайма.

```
java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/place/where/gluegen-rt.so/or/dll/located/ ....
```